# How to count elements in a JSON array

Tags: json, mule, anypoint-studio

I want to get the count of **faultInfoLst** element from the below json array. I want to do an operation based on the count of that element. Help me to get count as I have to set it in session variable in mule flow.

```
[{"TaskInfo":
    {"faultInfo":
        {
            "errCode":"",
            "errDesc":"",
            "errSystem":""
        }
    }
},
{"TaskInfo":
    {"faultInfo":
        {
            "errCode":"",
            "errDesc":"",
            "errSystem":"",
            "errStack":""
        }
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your goal can be achieved by simply getting the size of the array. It seems there's indeed a 1:1 relationship with `faultInfo` and `TaskInfo`.

So based on: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips#MuleExpressionLanguageTips-JSONProcessing

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" />
<set-variable variableName="faultInfoCount"
    value="#[($ in message.payload if $.TaskInfo.containsKey('faultInfo')).size()]" />
```

Comment: no david,fault info comes in taskinfo only if fault exists in the response.so it may come or may not come.i.e sometimes fault comes in taskinfo and some times it doesnt come.

Comment: OK this wasn't clear from your example. I'll refactor my answer.

Comment: Done, this new version filters the `TaskInfo` elements based on the existence of `faultInfo`.